# Include string in the function

Tags: pyspark

I have a function. This function is being used in my viewer so that only expressions like

Numbers and symbols !|& are included are included and remaining will throw an error message:

Now I also want to include an additional condition so that my viewer would not throw an error when it is typed.

How can I modify the regular expression such that It can also include string  in the regular expression?

Comment: Please include some examples of expected inputs and outputs

Comment: `re.sub('all|[^A-F0-9x\\|&!()]', '', str(my_string))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that would delete the string `all` but I think OP's goal is to *not* delete it? I'm not sure exactly what the question is

Comment: @mousetail sorry for the unclear question. I want to include the string all in the expression

Comment: @bella_pa that doesn't explain anything. Please [edit] your question to provide some examples of inputs and outputs to the function.

Comment: `re.sub('(all)|[^A-F0-9x\\|&!()]', r'\1', str(my_string))`? It is not quite clear if you validate or replace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot this works. So it is string validation - which is being done in the next part of the code. But in the question, it is string replace. what is the meaning of `r'\1'`?

Comment: I explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'(all)|[^A-F0-9x\\|&!()]', r'\1', str(my_string))
```

*Details*:

- `(all)` - **a capturing group** with ID 1 that matches `all` char sequence
- `|` - or
- `[^A-F0-9x\\|&!()]` - any char other than uppercase ASCII letters from `A` to `F`, digits, `x`, `\`, `|`, `&`, `!`, `(` and `)`.

The replacement pattern is `\1`, that is, the value of the capturing group with ID 1.

Comment: I still have one small doubt. `return re.sub('[^A-F0-9x\\|&!()]', '', str(my_string))`, Here if the pattern matches the condition the replacement is empty string. In your answer `\1` is used, But how are we getting empty string as expected ?

Comment: @bella_pa Please provide a test case: input and expected output.

Comment: `regularize_string("test")` would give empty string- as per your code and my code. But in my code I specifically gave the replacement as empty string where as you have written as '\1'. Then how is it replacing with empty string?

Comment: @bella_pa `\1` is empty if Group 1 did not participate in the match. So, if `all` matches, the replacement is `all`, else, it is an empty string.

Comment: @bella_pa What is still not clear or not working? Please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are capable of accepting entire words.

Square brackets are meant for character class, and you're actually trying to match the chars into your square brackets.

You need to change the 3rd line like this:

`return re.sub('[^A-F0-9x\\|&!()]|all', '', str(my_string))`

Remember to change also the previous comment line to:

```
# Keep only the relevant characters in the my_string + the word "all"
```

Note: Non-capture groups tell the engine that it doesn't need to store the match, while the other one (capturing group does). For small stuff, either are good, for 'heavy duty' stuff, you might want to see first if you need the match or not. If you don't, better use the non-capture group to allocate more memory for calculation instead of storing something you will never need to use.